# DataGridView извлечение информации

Tags: c#

Курил форумы и встал вопрос :

Есть `DataGridView`, вытягивает информацию из SQLite 3 таблицы, полет нормальный.

Есть рядом `RichTextBlock`, как при выделении строки в `DataGridView` отображать всю информацию из строки в этот текст блок рядом, и потом при перемещении со строки на строку динамически её обновлять?

Больше чем динамического отображения индексов строк и столбцов вытянуть ничего не смог.

Comment: а что мешает при клики обработать его примерно так 
this.SomeTextBox.Value = this.StartDataView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value . Где i и j индексы которые можно вычитать? Соответственно можно и по строке пройти через foreach(var cells in  this.StartDataView.Rows[i].Cells).

Comment: Можно использовать DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                  richTextBox1.Text += " " +dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                }
        }
```